# SSISDB rename for maintenance

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, ssis, sql-server-2017

We have an SSISDB database that has become too large and we wanted to do some maintenance on it. I've read that you shouldn't rename the SSISDB database as it would break links to existing packages, catalogs, etc. However, from what I've read I think this might work but wanted to get a feel if anyone else has done something similar. We're thinking of restoring a backup of the database into a copy named SSISDB2, then doing the maintenance on that version of the database. After this is done, we would rename the existing SSISDB to something like SSISDB_old, then SSISDB2 to SSISDB. In theory, replacing the old SSISDB with the new, cleaned up version. I'm thinking that the links to SSISDB breaking on rename would be due to hard-coded lookups for the database name itself, and by renaming everything after cleanup was complete, that things should just "work".  Does this make sense, has anyone else done something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer as I only have partial knowledge.

Packages, configurations, environment variables, etc are all in the SSISDB. There's an `internal` schema for such things and they expose the "pretty" versions under the `catalog` schema.

So, swapping SSISDB in/out won't cause any packages to start working or behave differently unless someone deploys a new version or configures a package during your maintenance time.

When you swap vClean back into place, you will have lost any execution history that would have been in vOld as they were separated at that point.

I covered some of this over on SO along with links to resources that cover how to roll your own cleanup scripts as the native ones use cascading deletes to maintain RI plus 2012 didn't have good indexes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781351/how-can-i-clean-up-the-ssisdb